# How can I position this DIV in exactly the middle and it isn't moved while resizing the browser?

Tags: html, css

You'll probably need this, thanks in advance. Also how can the text inside the DIV also be positioned in the middle?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#questiond {
  width: 1080px;
  height: 675px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
#frage1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #f09b72
}
```

```html
<body background="img/bg.jpg">
  <div id="questiond">
    <h1 id="frage1">Frage 1</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I hope you are looking for this one below

```css
#questiond {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
```

```html
<div id="questiond">
    <h1 id="frage1">Frage 1</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To put in in the "middle" - both vertically and horizontally, you can do this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#questiond {
  width: 1080px;
  height: 675px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
#frage1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;top:50%;bottom:auto;
  translateY(-50%);
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #f09b72
}
```

```html
<body background="img/bg.jpg">
  <div id="questiond">
    <h1 id="frage1">Frage 1</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```